# cannot resolve error. Missing a jar file?

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

```
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext;
import ca.uhn.hl7v2.HapiContext;
```

I'm getting a cannot resolve error for the above two lines. I don't know why, when I have all the jar files in my project. I'm just starting out using the `hapi` api so I might be missing something pretty easy to spot.

Comment: Have you specified them in your classpath?

Comment: Have you tried using `import ca.uhn.hl7v2.*;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of HAPI do you (intend to) use? HapiContext and its implementation are only available starting as of HAPI 2.1-beta1. Probably you have an older HAPI version in your classpath.

Comment: Where can I get the 2.1 beta then? There is only a link for the 2.0 api